# I am stuck at a JavaScript function that should count all unique items in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I wanted to create a function, that counts all unique Items in an array, but somehow I do not get any output. 
This is my array!
`let arr = ["hi", "hello", "hi"];`

And this is the code I wrote so far:

```
function countUnique(arr) {
  var counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counts[arr[i]] = 1 + (counts[arr[i]] || 0);
  }

  countUnique(arr);
}

console.log(countUnique(arr));
```

Comment: you're not getting an output because `countUnique` keeps being called, leading to a _Maximum call stack size exceeded_ error. Instead, you need to `return counts` (the object) rather than re-calling `countUnique`

Answer (score 1):

Your are counting values correctly, however then you are calling this method recursively `countUnique(arr);` and it results an error of *call stack exceeded*. 
So just remove recursive call of method `countUnique(arr);` and return counted value `counts`:

```js
function countUnique(arr) {
  var counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    counts[arr[i]] = 1 + (counts[arr[i]] || 0);
  }

  return counts;
}

let arr = ["hi", "hello", "hi"];
console.log(countUnique(arr));
```

JavaScript engine limits the maximal recursion depth. [We can rely on it being 10000, some engines allow more.](https://javascript.info/recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and return the `size`.

```js
const countUnique = array => new Set(array).size;

console.log(countUnique(["hi", "hello", "hi"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["hi", "hello", "hi"];

function countUnique(arr) {
  var counts = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] in counts) {
      counts[arr[i]]++;
    } else {
      counts[arr[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return Object.keys(counts).length;
}

console.log(countUnique(arr));
```